# regular expression with variable not replace text like normal expression does

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to put a variable into a regular expression but the string isn't replacing like the first data1 variable

```js
var data1 = "value=first_name=John&last_name=Doe;"
  .replace(/(value\=).*(;)/g, '$1first_name=Homer&last_name=Simspon$2');

console.log(data1);

var key = 'value';

var data2 = "value=first_name=John&last_name=Doe;"
  .replace(new RegExp(`/(${key}\=).*(;)/`, 'g'), '1$first_name=Foo&last_name=Bar2$');
    
console.log(data2);
```

```html
data2 should output: value=first_name=Foo&last_name=Bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite close! No need of the `/`s when using `new RegExp()` and it's `$1` and `$2` not `1$` and `2$`:

```
var key = 'value';

var data2 = "value=first_name=John&last_name=Doe;"
  .replace(new RegExp(`(${key}\\=).*(;)`, 'g'), '$1first_name=Foo&last_name=Bar$2');
```

**DEMO**

```js
var data1 = "value=first_name=John&last_name=Doe;"
  .replace(/(value\=).*(;)/g, '$1first_name=Homer&last_name=Simspon$2');

console.log(data1);

var key = 'value';

var data2 = "value=first_name=John&last_name=Doe;"
  .replace(new RegExp(`(${key}=).*(;)`, 'g'), '$1first_name=Foo&last_name=Bar$2');
    
console.log(data2);
```

```html
data2 should output: value=first_name=Foo&last_name=Bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Forward slashes are delimiters for *regex literals*. If you're using `new RegExp`, the delimiters being used are the delimiters for the *string* you're passing into it (if you have such a string literal at all).

The following regex:

```
const regex = new RegExp('/foo/');
```

is equivalent to:

```
const regex = /\/foo\//;
```

A literal forward slash gets matched. So, with the regex constructor, you need to remove the forward slashes:

```js
var key = 'value';

var data2 = "value=first_name=John&last_name=Doe;"
  .replace(new RegExp(`(${key}\=).*(;)`, 'g'), '$1first_name=Foo&last_name=Bar$2');
    
console.log(data2);
```

```html
data2 should output: value=first_name=Foo&last_name=Bar
```

Note that you have to use `$1` and `$2`, not `1$` and `2$`.

You can make it a bit more elegant by

- not escaping the `=` (it's not a special character)
- not capturing the `;`, just match it normally (and replace with `;` at the end instead of `$2`)

```js
var key = 'value';

var data2 = "value=first_name=John&last_name=Doe;"
  .replace(new RegExp(`(${key}=).*;`, 'g'), '$1first_name=Foo&last_name=Bar;');
    
console.log(data2);
```

```html
data2 should output: value=first_name=Foo&last_name=Bar
```